# GraphPlot labels overlapping

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

If I plot the following graph with an `EdgeRenderingFunction`, the position of both the labels are at dead center, and with a large graph I have the labels completely overlapping each other:

```
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {2 -> 1, "b"}}, 
  DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCoordinateRules -> Automatic, VertexLabeling -> True, 
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, Arrow[#1, 0.1],
     If[#3 =!= None, Text[Style[#3, Medium], Mean[#1], Background -> White], {}]} &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a way to position the labels, say, at 60% down the edge instead of dead center, so that the labels don't have a chance to overlap? I've been toggling with `Mean[#1]` above but can't get this right positioning.

Edit: improved formatting

Comment: Edit: The following is a hackish way to do it: `If[Length[#1] > 2, Mean[#1] + (#1[[1]] - #1[[2]])*0.5, Mean[#1]]`, but I would be open to more suggestions.

Comment: Also hackish: `Mean[#1[[4 ;;]]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed["a", {1/2, {1, 1.5}}], 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> Placed["b", {1/2, {1, 1.5}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is this the new font default for v10 or did you set fontfamily beforehand? I would welcome a default sans serif label style!

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to position the labels, say, at 60% down the edge instead of dead center*

You can use the function `LineScaledCoordinate` from the `GraphUtilities` package to set the position of the label along the curve:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {2 -> 1, "b"}}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> Automatic, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, Arrow[#1, 0.1], 
   If[#3 =!= None, Text[Style[#3, Medium], LineScaledCoordinate[#, .6], 
       Background -> White], {}]} &)]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {1 -> 2, "b"} , {2 -> 1, "c"}, {2 -> 1, "d"}}, 
  DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCoordinateRules -> Automatic, 
  VertexLabeling -> True, 
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, Arrow[#1, 0.1], If[#3 =!= None, 
   Text[Style[#3, Medium, Background -> White], 
       Switch[#3, "a" | "c", LineScaledCoordinate[#, .6], _,  
        LineScaledCoordinate[#, .3]]], {}]} &)]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative that does not require the ``GraphUtilities``` package is to replace `LineScaledCoordinate[#, s]` above with `BezierFunction[#][s]`.